# Why GBQ doesn't work when I try to change it to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, service-accounts, pandas.dataframe.to-gbq

I want to load and write data on my GBQ. I tried to use `read_gbq()` and followed the instructions for the authenticating. I used my service account for authentication. I referred to the official documentation of `pandas_gbq` shown below:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas_gbq

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'path/to/key.json',
)
df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql, project_id="YOUR-PROJECT-ID", credentials=credentials)
```

This throws an error. This is the error I am getting:

`AttributeError: module 'google.auth.credentials' has no attribute 'CredentialsWithTokenUri'`

I then tried to use the BigQuery Client for Python. I used the BigQuery documentation to authenticate. This is what I did:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path =  'creds/my-cred-file.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id)
```

When I ran the query through:

`query_job = client.query(sql)`

This returns the data where I can iterate through. So, the data from the tables are being read using this method. But when I tried this:

`query_job.to_dataframe()`

It throws me an error, `PermissionDenied: 403 request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'projects/my-project-staging'`.

I want to know if something is wrong with my service account. I feel like it shouldn't be, because I am able to read data by iterating through `query_job` variable. Is there any sort of documentation that would help me?

I tried to read and load data from GBQ. I was expecting I could easily turn the result into pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error it appears that the user has a missing permission. I would suggest to add this role to the service account to test if it help to resolve your error

> BigQuery Read Session User

[image]

Reference:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage

You can also check the status of your service account key at the keys tab when you select your SA:

[image]

Also I would suggest following this documentation on [Pandas-gbq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) for your reference, and also [this](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-gbq/) for installation of the package.